# Android Xposed Hook PackageManagerService Didn't find class "com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService"

Tags: android, xposed

Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService"

```
public class HookAPM_6 implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {

@Override
public void handleLoadPackage(XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {

    Class<?> packageManagerService = XposedHelpers.findClass("com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService",
            lpparam.classLoader);

    XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(packageManagerService, "installPackageLI",
            "com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.InstallArgs",
            "com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.PackageInstalledInfo",
            new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    super.beforeHookedMethod(param);
                }
            });
```

please~

When I use the above code to hook the system service (packagemanagerservice), it will report an error. The specific error is: "caused by: java.lang.classnotfoundexception: com.android.server.pm. PackageManagerService"

what's wrong please? and How should I write it？

The device is running Android 6.0.1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Xposed is applied to each and every app installed on your device. The error simply means that the class is not present in every app respectively every "package" that is loaded (which is not a surprise).

Comment: OK, thank you. How should I write it?

Comment: Usually you only apply hooks to those app(s) you want to hook and where you know the class you hook is present. https://riptutorial.com/android/example/16248/hooking-a-method